# Strange Behaviour of C

Tags: c

[image: Example output 1]

I am learning c language and am trying to put values into the character array of size 10 through while loop. But strangely the scanf part of loop body is working for every 2nd iteration only.
I am attaching the screenshot. Please anyone tell me what is the mistake that i made.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char str[10],ch;printf("please enter the first element:");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    int count=0;//insertion of element into the array
    while((count<10) && (ch!=EOF))
    {
        str[count]=ch;
        printf("please enter the %dth element:",count);
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        count=count+1;
    }
    printf("\ninsertion done successfully");
}
```

[image: Example output 2]

I have checked the code, but found no reason for such result and have also tried different compilers of c but ended with same result.

Comment: When you type something like `a` and hit return, you've typed two characters.  The `%c` conversion specification, like `%[…]` scansets and `%n`, do not skip white space.  Use `" %c"` as the format string.  Also note that if you read 10 characters, you will not have a string — you will have a byte array without a null terminator.  You can increase the array size to 11 or accept up to 9 characters, and either way, you should add the null terminator when the loop completes.

Comment: @fukanchik: why?  If fewer than 10 characters have been read ___and___ the last character read was not EOF (and it never will be; `scanf()` returns EOF, but doesn't assign `EOF` to any of its arguments), then continue.  Besides, using `(count < 10) || (ch != EOF)` would overflow the array if the user kept typing, wouldn't it?

Comment: `ch` won't be `EOF` at end of file, `scanf` doesn't work like that: it won't input *any* value to `ch.` I suggest you change the loop control to `while(count < 10  && scanf(" %c", &ch) == 1)`. Note the added space before `%` to filter the previous newline.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  char str [10], ch;
  int count = 0;//insertion of element into the array
  while (count < 10) {
      printf ("please enter the %dth element:", count);
      scanf (" %c", &ch);
      str [count] = ch;
      count = count + 1;
    }
  printf ("\ninsertion done successfully");
  return 0;
}